# How do I create a csv file and upload it to the server folder using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My program takes a 2D array and converts it into a csv that is able to be downloaded like this:

```
var csvRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < twoDiArray.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < twoDiArray[i].length; ++j) {
        twoDiArray[i][j] = '\"' + twoDiArray[i][j] + '\"';  // Handle elements that contain commas
        twoDiArray[i][j] = twoDiArray[i][j].replace(/ /g, '%20'); 
    }
    csvRows.push(twoDiArray[i].join(','));
}

var csvString = csvRows.join('\r\n');
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'MD_Database_with_Coords.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

How do I then save this file **without uploading it again** to the server folder so that I could load it using another window (that uses php to access the cvs file) immediately after. My php code for the new window is:

```
<?php       
//opens file
$file = fopen("MD_Database_with_Coords.csv","r");
$array_of_array = array();
$counter = 0;

//reads entries
while(!feof($file)) {
  $array_entry = fgetcsv($file);

  //ignore first line
  if ($array_entry[0] == "﻿ID") {
    continue;
  }

  //fill array with entries
  if ($array_entry != NULL) {
    $array_of_array[$counter] = $array_entry;  
  }

  $counter++;
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: If you're just uploading it to display it to the user, why are you trying to upload it in the first place?

Comment: It utilizes the google geocode API that has a query limit. In order for users to load the display instantly, all of the database has to be calculated beforehand so the user won't have to wait. Thus, if an admin decides to use to use a new database, they just have to wait for the coords to be calculated once. Then the file is uploaded to the server and all future displays will be instantaneous.